# how to hide UIMenuController in iOS 5

Tags: uitextview, hide, ios5, uimenucontroller

In my app I need to select some text in UITextview(editable) but I don't want to show UIMenuController popover.

In previous iOS, I override

```
(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

of UIResponder and set the return value to NO. 
But after I used IOS 5 GM, the UIMenuController popover still doesn't hide. 
I tried to set the return value to YES, but it's still the same. Can anyone tell me how to hide it in iOS5?

Thank you, 
regards,

Risma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614465/how-do-you-really-remove-copy-from-uimenucontroller/7944656#7944656). Basically need to subclass UITextView (or UIWebView). Works fine on iOS5 too.