# Disable paste in uitextfield in iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextfield, paste, uimenucontroller

I'm attempting to disable paste in a textfield using the following code:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

  if ([UIMenuController sharedMenuController]) {

    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;

  }

  return NO;
}
```

I've this code in other projects and its worked, however in my current project it just gets called multiple times and then displays the paste menu item.

This only thing that I can see that is different is that in this project the viewcontroller where the above code lives is the child of a custom viewcontroller.

EDIT

It's not showing the menu option when I run it with in the simulator with iOS4.3 as opposed to iOS5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got there in the end. Instead of placing the code into the viewcontroller, i subclassed UITextField and placed it in there and it works.

I based it on the example here:

[How do you REALLY remove Copy from UIMenuController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614465/how-do-you-really-remove-copy-from-uimenucontroller/7944656#7944656)

Comment: Yeah, I found that subclassing the UITextField works in Xcode 5.1. I had the same issue and after much struggling with it came up with this more detailed outline. You are free to use it if you like. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514104/how-do-prevent-a-copy-paste-select-popover-on-a-uitextview-using-uimenucontrolle