# How do Prevent a copy/paste/select popover on a UITextView using UIMenuController iOS5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, xcode5.1, uimenucontroller

**The question**: How do I **prevent** the copy/paste/select popup that occurs over a **UITextView** from appearing (not using **UIwebView** and css)?

I did not want to go the rout of **UIWebView** as some posts have gone because I already am using **UIViews** with **UITextFields** for data entry. I had tried *unsuccessfully* to implement the solutions dealing with **UITextField** in my implementation file of my view controller with the methods: *targetForAction:withSender*, *setMenuVisible:animated* and finally *canPerformAction:withSender*. (It NO WORKY WORKY - [sad face])

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: reformatted with my original question. thanks!

Comment: Your "question" is still more of an answer. If your goal is to answer your own "question" because you think it will help other people than split it up into an actual question and post an actual answer below.

Comment: Ok -- I posted the solution to my dilemma below. i hope this is clearer and helps some folks in their adventures in iOS land!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a **working solution** (in **Xcode 5.1**) to my question which, in short, is subclassing the **UITextField**.

I realized I wasn't really overriding the default behavior of the **UITextField** in the view controller like I wanted to and neither was putting the methods listed here override the behavior of the textfield delegate in the view controller file. The **Key** was to subclass the **UITextField** itself with *-targetForAction:withSender*. (I know some of you are screaming at the screen about how **OBVIOUS** that was!) It was *not* obvious to me. Like most problems when first figuring them out I went through a lot of different paths some I found here in SO. But the solution is a simple one. I want to share this solution in its own area so hopefully it can help someone out.

The header file:

```
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TPTextField : UITextField

- (id)targetForAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender;
@end
```

and the implementation file (.m)

```
//
//

#import "TPTextField.h"

@implementation TPTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
#pragma mark - method overrides - deny user copy/paste on UITTextFields
- (id)targetForAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (action == @selector(selectAll:) || action == @selector(paste:) ||action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(cut:)) {
        if (menuController) {
            [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return [super targetForAction:action withSender:sender];
}

@end
```

In your storyboard or nib/xib file just connect this class to your UITextfield like the picture below:

[image: Custom Class:TPTextfield]

I have it on git to for easy access [here](https://github.com/Urded/TPTextField). Please let me know if this is helpful to you!

Tony

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what `canPerformAction:withSender:` is for. You should not implement `targetForAction:withSender:`.

Comment: What is the reason you should not use targetForAction:withSender:? @quellish

Comment: The UIResponder documentation. `canPerformAction:withSender:` allows customization of the menu commands. That is how the application knows wether the edit menu commands should be available in a given context. `targetForAction:withSender:` is what connects a command with a target - AFTER `canPerformAction:withSender:` is called to validate that the command should be available. You want to make the menu commands not available - `canPerformAction:withSender:` is the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the UITextView is created as an object on a storyboard, the solution is even easier. In Attributes Inspector for the UITextView object, under Behavior, uncheck Editable and uncheck Selectable. Under the Scroll View section, you can check Scrolling Enabled if you want the user to be able to scroll text.