# disable 'copy' in uiwebview but not 'select'.

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I like to disable 'copy' in uiwebview but not the 'select' option. How do I do this? This is because I am using window.getSelection() in my JavaScript that selects the user selection and does some processing on it. The 'copy' uimenucontrolleritem and the 'copy' features that open up are not required and confuses the user's of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from an answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614465/how-do-you-really-remove-copy-from-uimenucontroller

First your UIWebView needs to be from subclass of UIWebView. In XCode go to File -> new -> File... and add a new Objective-c class named "MyUIWebView" and make it a subclass of UIWebView.

In your MyUIWebView.m file add the following

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
if (action == @selector(copy:))
    return NO;
else if (action == @selector(select:))
    return YES;

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

From here link your class up with your viewcontroller(s) that contain your UIWebView and go through your code and replace all instances of UIWebView with MyUIWebView.

Just tested on the ios 6.1 simulator and it seemed to work.

Comment: many thanks!! I am going to test this when I reach home tonight and will let you know how that goes.

Comment: Is it possible to disable the zoom/magnifying lens on uiwebview, but keep the selection?