# UimenuController-How to remove default menu items

Tags: ios, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

how to remove defaults menu items like copy ,paste and select from UIMenuController

Comment: Depends on the circumstances. Where are you? UITextField? UITableView?

Comment: I want to disable these menu's in UIWebView textfields. i e for html textfields

Comment: See discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614465/how-do-you-really-remove-copy-from-uimenucontroller?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Return NO from `canPerformAction:...`. (Exactly which `canPerformAction:` this is, depends on where you are; your question gives no information on that.)

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Thanks for the reply.I tried this but still those default menu's remains there.I want to do this on the textfields on UIWebView