# Override "Look Up" menu item on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenuitem

When you select text in iOS one of the menu items is called "Look Up".

Is it possible to override this behavior and display your own view controller?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614465/how-do-you-really-remove-copy-from-uimenucontroller

Answer (score 1):

You can override these commands and provide custom controls via the UIMenuController and UIMenuItem classes:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller
- https://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/

  > #### UIMenuItem
  >
  > With iOS 3.2, developers could now add their own commands to the menu controller. As yet unmentioned, but familiar commands like “Define” or spell check suggestions take advantage of this.
  >
  > UIMenuController has a menuItems property, which is an NSArray of UIMenuItem objects. Each UIMenuItem object has a title and action. In order to have a menu item command display in a menu controller, the responder must implement the corresponding selector.